# How to change greek letters in MathPTMX package to default font?

Tags: greek, computer-modern, mathptmx

I really like the greek letters of the default LaTeX font but I want the rest of the characters to be in Times New Roman using the Mathptmx font. I find the greek letters of the mathptmx package rather ugly since they're disproportionately bolder than the usual text. [image: greek letters of Mathptmx]

So may I know how can I change the greek characters only and retain the times new roman text? I have tried many suggestions from countless websites but to no avail. Alternatively, can I ask if there's a way to change the greek letters somewhat more similar to the greek letters in the books like those in University Physics by Young and Freedman?

Comment: unless you are forced to I wouldn't use the legacy mathptm(x) packages, a more modern supported times-like setup would be a better start such as `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` or `\usepackage{stix2}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am having trouble using those packages as these require a different compilation setting if I remember correctly.

Comment: no, both should work with pdflatex exactly like mathptmx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as David Carlisle pointed out in the comments, if you want to use a Times clone it would be better to use the more recent [`newtx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/newtx) bundle than `mathptmx`, which is now obsolete.

Now, to strictly answer your question, after loading `mathptmx` you can redeclare all greek letters in the Computer Modern font (which is the default font). This will work just as well if `newtx` is loaded instead of `mathptmx`, by the way. Here's a complete example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmletters}{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{cmletters}{10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{cmletters}{11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{cmletters}{12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathord}{cmletters}{13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathord}{cmletters}{14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{cmletters}{15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathord}{cmletters}{16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathord}{cmletters}{17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathord}{cmletters}{18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathord}{cmletters}{19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathord}{cmletters}{20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{letters}{21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{cmletters}{22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{cmletters}{23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{cmletters}{24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{cmletters}{25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathord}{cmletters}{26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathord}{cmletters}{27}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{cmletters}{28}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathord}{cmletters}{29}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{cmletters}{30}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{cmletters}{31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathord}{cmletters}{32}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathord}{cmletters}{33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathord}{cmletters}{34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathord}{cmletters}{35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathord}{cmletters}{36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathord}{cmletters}{37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathord}{cmletters}{38}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathord}{cmletters}{39}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1 \\
\alpha + \beta + \pi
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

---

Since you mention in the question that the reason you wish to change the greek letters is that they seem too bold compared to the rest of the text, I thought it would be relevant to point out that the weight of the letters from `newtx` is certainly more balanced than that of the letters from `mathptmx`. Here's how it looks with only `newtx`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtx}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) = 1 \\
\alpha + \beta + \pi
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```